C# Restaurant Cashier - Dynamic Button Color Matching with Product Category item
I am working on designing a cashier win app for restaurants in C# to facilitate the sorting process. On the right side, the categories appear in the form of buttons from the database, and just as the colors of the buttons change randomly, I want the color of the products (category) that is in green in the products (items) to be the same Button color of categories.
CODE C# :
     Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton b2 = new Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton();
       private Random rnd = new Random();
        private void AddCategory()
        {
            string qry = "select * from category";
            SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(qry, MainClass.con);
            SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmmd);
            DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
            daa.Fill(dtt);
            categoryPanel.Controls.Clear();

            if (dtt.Rows.Count >0)
            {
                Color RandomColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));
                b2.BaseColor = RandomColor;
                b2.Size = new Size(134, 45);
                b2.Text = allcat.ToString();
                b2.Click += new EventHandler(_Click);
                categoryPanel.Controls.Add(b2);

                foreach (DataRow row in dtt.Rows)
                {           
                    Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton b = new Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton();
                    Color RandomColor2 = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));
                    b.BaseColor = RandomColor2;
                    b.Location = new Point(b.Location.X - 10, b.Location.Y+dtt.Rows.Count);
                    b.Size = new Size(134, 45);
                    b.Text = row["catName"].ToString();
                    b.Click += new EventHandler(_Click);
                    b.OnPressedColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 5, 0);
                    categoryPanel.Controls.Add(b);
                }
            }
            
            else
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = "No Category Found!";
                categoryPanel.Controls.Add(lbl);
            }

        }
        private void _Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblorderID.Text = MainID.ToString();
            Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton b =  (Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaButton)sender;
            b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 55, 89);
            if (b.Text == allcat)
            {
                txtSearch.Text = "1";
                txtSearch.Text = "";
                return;
            }
                foreach (var item in itemsPanel.Controls)
                {
                    var pro = (UC.ucProduct)item;
                    pro.Visible = pro.PCategory.ToLower().Contains(b.Text.Trim().ToLower());   
                }

                b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
        }

        private void AddItem(string id,string proID, string name, string cat, string price, Image pimage)
        {
            lblorderID.Text = MainID.ToString();
            var w = new UC.ucProduct()
            {
                PName = name,
                PPrice = price,
                PCategory = cat,
                PImage = pimage,
                id = Convert.ToInt32(proID)
            };

            w.btnMin.Image = global::Dotcresturant.Properties.Resources.plus;

            itemsPanel.Controls.Add(w);
            w.onSelect +=(ss,ee) =>
                {
                    var wdg= (UC.ucProduct)ss;
                    validation = 1;
                    ktnbtn.Enabled = true;
                    wdg.btnMin.Image = global::Dotcresturant.Properties.Resources.delete;


                    BL.ControlVar s = new BL.ControlVar();




                    s.set_IDPRO( Convert.ToInt32(proID));
                    Model.frmSizeSelect selectsize = new frmSizeSelect();
                    MainClass.BlueBackground(selectsize);
                    foreach(DataGridViewRow item in gunaDataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["dvgprodID"].Value) == wdg.id)
                        {
                            item.Cells["dvgqty"].Value = int.Parse(item.Cells["dvgqty"].Value.ToString()) + 1;
                            item.Cells["dvgAmount"].Value = int.Parse(item.Cells["dvgqty"].Value.ToString()) *
                            double.Parse(item.Cells["dvgprice"].Value.ToString());
                            GetTotal();
                            return;
                        }

                     }        
                    //add new product
                    gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {0, 0, wdg.id, wdg.PName, 1, wdg.PPrice, wdg.PPrice });
                    GetTotal(); 
                };

            w.onSelectMin += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                var wdg = (UC.ucProduct)ss;
                //validation = 1;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in gunaDataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["dvgprodID"].Value) == wdg.id)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["dvgqty"].Value) <= 1)
                        {
                            //var wdg = (UC.ucProduct)ss;
                            wdg.btnMin.Image = global::Dotcresturant.Properties.Resources.plus;

                            gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Remove(item);
                            GetTotal();
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            item.Cells["dvgqty"].Value = int.Parse(item.Cells["dvgqty"].Value.ToString()) - 1;
                            item.Cells["dvgAmount"].Value = int.Parse(item.Cells["dvgqty"].Value.ToString()) *
                                double.Parse(item.Cells["dvgprice"].Value.ToString());
                            GetTotal();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

Results :
Results
